# How to get the current cursor from a WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm having problems with getting the current cursor from the WinForm WebBrowser control. It's always returning the Default cursor.

Mouse cursor changes depending on what element it currently is on. If it's over a link then the Cursor changes to "Hand"; if on a TextBox then it becomes an "IBeam". So, I want to somehow get that information.

Cursor.Current gives me the right cursor, if the WebBrowser control is placed on a WinForm but not when it is hosted in WPF.